# What is the name of the IC that runs a low-harmonic power supply?

Tags: integrated-circuit, ac, pwm, boost, ac-dc

I'm interested in building an AC/DC converter for low-harmonic applications. Single-phase AC input, followed by a rectifier and a PWM-controlled boost converter. I know there are ICs which are designed specifically to run converters of this type, but I'm not seeing any obvious keywords. What should I be looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be PFC, for power factor correction.

http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-pfc-power-factor-correction/2556705